# Getting the IP address of remote server in PHP

Tags: php

I'm in the process of building my first API driven app.  I am looking for a way to retrieve the server IP address that is making the request.

Here's the workflow.

`[User Website] => Sends Auth Request To [API Server]`

When the user makes the auth request from their website, I want the API server to retrieve the IP address of the users website.  Right now, I've went through `$_SERVER` and it will either give me MY IP address from the API server or it will give me the IP address of the Users computer, NOT the IP address from their website.

Here's an example

`[user:24.64.64.192] => BROWSER => [user-website:74.68.125.194] => API Request => [API Server:25.25.192.168]`

Right now I can only get either `25.25.192.168` or `24.64.64.192`.  What I need to get is `74.68.125.194`, {IP addresses are fictionalized}

So how can [API Server] retrieve `74.68.125.194` when the auth request is made?

Unless, I am missing something, the only thing I can think of doing is attaching the IP address as a parameter in my auth request

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For

Comment: You can't unless the user is authenticating to `user-website` which in turn calls `API`.  If the browser code the user is using is talking directly to the API it won't know anything about the site hosting the website.  And passing the IP as a parameter is easily modified.  If API server is seeing the browser IP, it means the browser code is directly authenticating to the API server without going through the server that provided the assets to the browser.

Comment: Basically, your question is invalid because the server is not making the API request.  The browser is.

Answer (score 0):

The IP Address of the device that made request is in `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];`

But if you are using a **reverse proxy** or client website is connecting to your server through standard proxy you will find proxy's IP there because it's proxy that is forwarding the request to your server. In that case you want to look for `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']` or `$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']` whether these values are set depends on the proxy.

As **@Joe** said in comments. If you can find the user's IP adress in these fields the request to API is coming directly from user's browser not from the user's website server. In that case you can't find the IP of website server because it's not involved in this request.
You might create some workaround (in JS) that would determine website server's IP and include it in API request.